# How to override generic method from my own bascontroller class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a base controller class, `MyBaseController`. How can I override the methods in another controller class which inherits from `MyBaseController`? The view model is different in every controller.

```
public class MyBaseController<T> : ControllerBase where T : class
{
    public VsBaseController()
    {
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public virtual async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync([FromQuery] string QueryParams)
    {
        return null;
    }

    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public virtual async Task<IActionResult> DeleteAsync(int id)
    {
        return null;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ServiceFilter(typeof(ValidationFilter))]
    protected virtual async Task<IActionResult> CreateAsync(T ViewModel)
    {
        return null;
    }

    [HttpPut]
    public virtual async Task<IActionResult> UpdateAsync(T ViewModel, int Id)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

In the descendent controller, I have the following code:

```
[HttpPost]
public override async Task<IActionResult> CreateAsync(MyViewModel ViewModel)
{
    var Response = await _MyService.New(ViewModel);
    return Response;
}
```

And when building the app I get the following error:

> CS0115: no suitable method found to override

Comment: What do you mean "how can I override the methods"?  Do you not know how to override methods in general?

Comment: Yes. I mean how can i for example override the CreateAsync method, because the viewmodel is different in every controller?

Comment: You just override like normal, except replace `T` with whatever type you pass to `MyBaseController` in your subclass.

Comment: Yes, i have this:         public override async Task<IActionResult> CreateAsync(AfspraakViewModel ViewModel)
        {
            var Response = await _afspraakService.NewAfspraak(ViewModel);
            return Response;
        }

Comment: Ok, and do you get an error?

Comment: and i get the following error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0115 'AfspraakController<>.CreateAsync(AfspraakViewModel)': no suitable method found to override VSAPI2 G:\NET_source\VSAPI2\VSAPI2\Controllers\AfspraakController.cs 29 Active

Comment: That is the most important part of your question, so you should edit your question to include that.  Please also include the code for the subclass, particularly how it's declared and what type you are passing to `MyBaseController`.

Comment: Ok. i'll do that

Comment: Thanks for updating the question, but you still haven't included how the subclass is declared.  How are you subclassing `MyBaseController`?  `: MyBaseController<????>`?

Comment: public class MyController: VsBaseController<MyClass>

Comment: Then that's your problem as `MyClass` is not `AfspraakViewModel`.

Comment: Thank you Kirk. That solved my problem. Another question: Does Validation filter works for all controllers?

Comment: You should ask a new question for that.  And you might as well mark Dawood's answer as accepted as he covers the same ground as these comments.  It'll also earn you a bit of rep.

Comment: Oke. Tnx for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the generic type in your derived Controller like the following example:

```
public class MyBaseController<T> : ControllerBase where T : class
    {
        public MyBaseController()
        {
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public virtual async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync([FromQuery] string QueryParams)
        {
            return null;
        }

        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public virtual async Task<IActionResult> DeleteAsync(int id)
        {
            return null;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        // [ServiceFilter(typeof(ValidationFilter))]
        protected virtual async Task<IActionResult> CreateAsync(T ViewModel)
        {
            return null;
        }

        [HttpPut]
        public virtual async Task<IActionResult> UpdateAsync(T ViewModel, int Id)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

So if you have a ViewModel called `MyModel` then use it like this:

```
    public class MyModel
    {

    }

    public class TestDerivedController : MyBaseController<MyModel>
    {
        public override Task<IActionResult> UpdateAsync(MyModel ViewModel, int Id)
        {
            return base.UpdateAsync(ViewModel, Id);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Dawood for your reply. I have changed to viewmodel and it's doesn't give any error now